# Nouveau driver doesn't recognize my GTX 1060

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

Whenever I use the Nouveau driver with my GTX 1060, the desktop is forced to use software rendering. It doesn't seem to recognize the GPU at all.

As far as I know, Unity 8 doesn't work with NVIDIA's proprietary drivers, so I need to use Nouveau.

Comment: That's why you install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Unity 8 doesn't work with NVIDIA's proprietary drivers.